# Laravel - Eloquent - Eager Loading - Constraints / Selection / Grouping

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, constraints, eager-loading

I find Eloquent's joining logic far more complicated than a typical prepared statement (read I hate it).

Can someone please help me translate the following query into a sensible eloquent query that is **wholly** eagerly-loaded?

```
SELECT  C.id,
        C.seo_alias
FROM store_variants AS A 
LEFT JOIN variants  AS B ON B.id = A.id_variant
LEFT JOIN products  AS C ON C.id = B.id_product
LEFT JOIN stores    AS D ON D.id = A.id_store
WHERE D.id = 123
AND A.isActive > 0
GROUP BY C.id;
```

one product - many variants

one variant - many stores

one store_variant - one store

The models are storeVariantModel, variantModel, productModel, storeModel. There are millions of rows.

The way I see it, this query contains filtered selection, joins, grouping and constraints, so it covers the majority of operations I encounter daily, so if anyone can solve this you have my sincere gratitude.

Thank you

EDIT: Using Laravel 5.2

EDIT: Solution #2:

Thanks to @Balraj for his help, this is basically the final solution I have been forced to use:

```
storeVariantModel::
    join(   'variants', 'variants.id_variant',  '=', 'store_variants.id')
    ->join( 'products', 'products.id',          '=', 'variants.id_product')
    ->join( 'stores',   'stores.id',            '=', 'store_variants.id_store')
    ->with([
        'variantModel.storeVariantModel.storeModel',
        'variantModel.productModel'
    ])
    ->select('variants.*')
    ->where('stores.id','=',123)
    ->where('store_variants.isActive','>',0)
    ->get();
```

Modifications: I am no longer using the 'GROUP BY'

Pros: I get models with relationships back, constraints on intermediate tables filter data as opposed to only eager-loading whatever data matches the constraints

Cons: Syntax is balls, I'm basically calling join twice, I am no longer doing a select for a limited set of columns

Comment: Can you provide details as to the relationships between the models? Name, cardinality, etc.

Comment: C has many B, B has many A, D has many A

Comment: What are the names? E.g. `$store->products`...

Comment: I've updated the question, Rob. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

```
storeVariantModel::join('variants.id_variant','=','store_variants.id')
          ->join('products','products.id','=','variants.id_product')
          ->join('stores','stores.id','=','store_variants.id_store')
          ->select(['products.id','products.seo_alias'])
          ->where('stores.id','=',123)
          ->where('store_variants.isActive','>',0)
          ->groupby('products.id')
          ->get();
```

**Update Answer**

Eloquent without groupby:

```
In productModel:
public function variants(){
    return $this->hasMany(variantModel::class,'id_product','id');
}

In variantModel:
public function store_variants(){
    return $this->hasMany(storeVariantModel::class,'id_variant','id);
}

In storeVariantModel:
public function stores(){
    return $this->hasOne(storeModel::class,'id','id_store');
}



productModel::with(['variants.store_variants.stores' => function($q){
    $q->where('id','=',123);
}])->whereHas('variants.store_variants', function($q){
    $q->where('isActive','>',0);
})->get();
```

Comment: I need to use eloquent, not query builder

Comment: Apologies, I thought you were making a DB:: call, actually your code returns a Model so it's totally usable, and as things stand this afternoon, yours is the only code that I can make work, and is the only one that is doing a proper join, not a subquery. So thank you!

Comment: @mils I tried using eager loading but because of that `groupBy` i cant  make it. So, i thought this is the only way to work it out.

Comment: This is the correct answer, @Balraj you are 100% correct, the group by will screw it up. If I can ask you a favour, can you post the eager-load solution without the groupBy? Thanks

Comment: @mils updated the answer. I haven't tested the code and please make sure it works. If any changes required do let me know!!. Also check if relationships are correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Following your description, C hasMany B, B hasMany A, D hasMany A.

You can eager load them with constraint like this

```
$result = CModel::with(['BRelationship' => function ($query) {
    $query->with(['ARelationship' => function ($sub1) {
        $sub1->with(['DRelationship' => function($sub2) {
            $sub3->where('id', '123);
        }]);
    }])->where('condition') //to add extra condition if you want
    ->groupBy('column'); //if you want to group by in ARelationship
}])->get();
```

You can read it as C with B with A with D.

I haven't tested this code so goodluck. Also don't forget to properly define relationships.

Comment: Trying your code now. The "with" conditions load the associated models, but every time I add a constraint like your "$sub3->where('id', '123);"  that model does not get loaded with the eager load. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure this is only pulling rows with that condition, or only eager-loading the rows that match the condition? Do you need to use "whereHas", in which case is it still eager loading?